# Ограничение использования Tab для фокуса по элементам.

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, javascript-events

Здравствуйте. Передо мной встала такая задача:

Делаю модальное окно с инпутами. Для для всех инпутов использую tabIndex.
Необходимо чтобы фокусировка по инпутам работала только внутри модального окна.
То есть если я нажимаю я область (не инпут) внутри модального окна, фокус не должен переходить на элементы за его пределами.

Сообразил костыль - отлавливать клик на области и фокусить контейнер модального окна, а уже затем отлавливать событие keydown на нажатие tab и в зависимости от того есть ли shiftKey - перемещать фокус на нужный инпут.

Буду рад вашему совету. Интересует - можно ли без костылей ограничить зону действия tab-фокуса.

Comment: Что если сделать tabindex динамическим :tabindex="modal ? -1 : value" ???

Comment: Вот там подробно все расписано. Гугл переводчик в помощь
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351983/how-to-limit-tab-indexes-to-just-an-overlay-and-its-elements